# Corrupted jpg files after copying from one hdd to another

Tags: image, file, jpeg, recover

Has anybody had such problem with corrupted jpg files?

I tried to recover them using softwares like File Repair or PixRecovery but they didn't help.

corrupted picture 1

[image]

corrupted picture 2

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. **We are here to help you troubleshoot or help you in the codes you provide.** Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) on how/where to post questions.

Comment: Looks like your file system on one of the disks, or the memory of the computer that did the copying, is corrupt. Either way, this is hardly a *programming question* so perhaps you should ask on [su]? You should provide more information as well since the answer to your question is just "Yes". Very many people experience corrupted files from time to time, it's just how mechanical storage devices work, they will inevitably fail. So if you just wanted a yes/no answer, consider it provided. Otherwise, provide more information about what you've tried (on [su]).

Comment: For instance, can you open the original file from the original disk? You say "copy", which implies the files was also left behind in their original state. In other words, can you actually read the source files?

Comment: I got a mess in Windows startup files and it wasn't able to start. So I removed the disk, copied all data by sata drive, cleaned the disk and reinstall Windows.
When I copied data back to formatted disk I noticed that all JPG files are damaged like pictures show.
I don't have original files.

Comment: On a disk to which I copied files pictures are also damaged, but I haven't noticed this fact earlier.